# React Native Gradle ImagePicker wont build

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle

When trying to build I get this error:

> Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.+ as no versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle are available.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
>   Required by:
>       project :react-native-image-picker

However when I change the tools version in the **Project gradle.build** to *2.2.3* I get this error:

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/1002 this should get you started.

Comment: everyone is having issue with maven() and jcenter(). Hand in there buddy.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347#comment30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They sent a new release and everything was fixed. **react-native-image-picker@0.27.2**

Comment: Your Answer worked for me, I didnt have to do what @John Miller said in his answer. Thanks

Comment: all i did was npm install react-native-image-picker@0.27.2

Answer (score 2):

Edit your build.gradle as following.

```
subprojects { subproject ->
    if (subproject.name.contains('react-native-image-picker')){
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

add this to build.gradle.

I think my issue is because they sent new release.

It can fix vector-icons and image-picker issue

```
subprojects {
    if (project.name.contains('react-native-image-picker') ||
        project.name.contains('react-native-vector-icons')) {
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
                maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```